# d3.js: dataset array w/ multiple y-axis values

Tags: d3.js

I am a total beginner to d3.js so please be kind :)

[considering this jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/edatol/1/edit)

I have the following dataset:

> ```
>       var dataset = [
>                       [d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), 1, 10], 
>                       [d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), 2, 20], 
>                       [d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), 3, 30], 
>                       [d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), 4, 40], 
>                       [d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), 5, 50], 
>                       [now, 6, 60],
>                     ];
> ```

Two questions.

1. Does d3 provide a better approach to finding the max value for my y-axis data (all columns but the 0th, the 0th column is x-axis (time)) in my dataset array? Currently I am just looping through the entire dataset array and making a second array, excluding the first column. Perhaps there is a better datastructure other than an array I should be using for this entirely?

   ```
       var data_arr = [];

       for (row in dataset){
           for (col=1;col < dataset[row].length; col++){
               data_arr.push(dataset[row][col]);
           }
       }

       var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0, d3.max(data_arr)])
                            .range([h - padding, padding]);
   ```
2. Once thats resolved, I still need to determine how to graph multiple y-axis values in general! This worked fine before I needed multiple y-axis values:

   ```
       svg.selectAll("circle")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d) {
               return xScale(d[0]);
          })
          .attr("cy", function(d) {
               return yScale(d[1]);
          })
          .attr("r", 2);
   ```

Please take a look at the graph w/ code here now for full context: http://jsbin.com/edatol/1/edit
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a couple of changes to your example and you can see the results at http://jsbin.com/edatol/2/edit.

First, I modified your data a little bit.  This is mostly just a style thing, but I find it's easier to work with objects instead of arrays:

```
        //Static dataset
        var dataset = [
          {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -5), y1: 1, y2: 10}, 
          {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -4), y1: 2, y2: 20},
          {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -3), y1: 3, y2: 30},
          {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -2), y1: 4, y2: 40},
          {x: d3.time.hour.utc.offset(now, -1), y1: 5, y2: 50},
          {x: now, y1: 6, y2: 60},
        ];
```

Then you can find your domains and ranges like this:

```
var xDomain = d3.extent(dataset, function(i) { return i.x; });
var maxY = d3.max(dataset, function(i) { return Math.max(i.y1, i.y2); });
```

Then to add multiple y-values, you just have to append an additional circle with the appropriate values.  I gave them different classes so that you can use that to select them if you want to do transitions or updates later on.

```
        //Create circles
        svg.selectAll(".y1")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
           .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y1); })
           .attr("class", "y1")
           .attr("r", 2);

        //Create circles
        svg.selectAll(".y2")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
           .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y2); })
           .attr("class", "y2")
           .attr("r", 2);
```